# custom control inside xslt file

Tags: asp.net, xslt, fckeditor

hallo all i am trying to put a custom server control
this time it happens to be an fckeditor control
inside my xslt file.

i use this file for custom generated forms

anyway i have no problem putting asp server controls inside the xslt but..
i get an error when i try to put a control with a diffrent namespace

here is the code:

```
<xsl:if test="@type='html'">
       <FCK:FCKeditor runat="server" ID="{@name}"></FCK:FCKeditor>
</xsl:if>
```

and this is the error:

'FCK' is an undeclared namespace

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the FCK namespace in your declarations with the other namespaces, similar to the xsl namespace.

Comment: i knew it must be something of that sort. but how do i do that?.. and where ?

Comment: @guy schaller: I recommend you to put the namespace declaration in your element root of the stylesheet. This way, the namespace would be in scope for every result node, and by the namespace fixup it would end up in your result element root.

Comment: ok.. what is the syntax for adding namespaces? do you maybe have an example? thank you

Comment: @guy schaller: `xmlns:FCK="what-ever-be-FCK-Uri"`